Как оформить комментарий героя после цитаты?
Перевожу отрывок из романа, и получилось вот такое предложение:
"(она) повесила в саду гамак, слушает радио. «Жизнь — это словарь, в котором каждый определяет сам себя». О, хорошо сказано, надо бы записать".
Не знаю, как оформить такую реакцию героини на цитату с радио. В оригинале её слова вплетены в речь автора, поэтому отдельно не выделяются. Будет интересно выслушать ваши варианты.

...она повесила в саду гамак, слушает радио. «Жизнь — это словарь, в котором каждый определяет сам себя». О, хорошо сказано, надо бы записать.

Я бы после слов "слушает радио" поставил двоеточие, потому что дальше предполагается слово "и слышит". У Розенталя пример: "Я поднял голову: передо мной на лодке сидела мельничиха"

Как вариант:
...она повесила в саду гамак, слушает радио. «Жизнь — это словарь, в котором каждый определяет сам себя». О, хорошо сказано, надо бы записать, думает она.
Или можно последнее предложение выделить в отдельный абзац. А иначе мысли не отделены от действия.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Другими словами, комментарий героя никак не обозначен, а ведь именно такая задача ставилась в вопросе. Если не использовать "думает она", то мы имеем несобственно-прямую речь, которую надо как-то выделять.
Или что мы имеем?  Нужна оценка такого приема построения текста. А иначе получается немного неряшливо, не по правилам. Но это уже авторский выбор.
Если все же такое оформление применяется на практике, то хотелось бы увидеть примеры из художественной литературы.  То есть решение задачи, если это действительно решение, должно быть обоснованным)
